# object is not an instance of declaring class on using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, urlclassloader

I am trying to load a class from a URL using java reflection and classLoader. The application is deployed on weblogic 12c server

```
        File f = new File("/a/abc");
        URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
        ClassLoader classLoader =  ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(classLoader, url);
        Class jobClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.test.abc");
```

However, I get the below error:

exception thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Please let me know what might be the issue here or if this is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: You're trying to modify the system classloader during runtime. There is no correct way to do that, so it's a good thing that you're getting errors.

Comment: I can't reproduce. On my machine, it got to the `loadClass` call.

Comment: So there is no way to do it at runtime?

Comment: @Sweeper that’s because on some systems, the system class load might be a `URLClassLoader`. Considering the widespread typical implementations, the OP is likely using Java 9 or newer, whereas you are using Java 8 or older.

Comment: @LearningJava when you want to load classes from a URL dynamically, you should create your own `URLClassLoader`. That’s the way to do it, which doesn’t even need Reflection with access override.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the method 'addURL' on a class of type ClassLoader. The class ClassLoader does not contain the member method 'addURL'. That's why you get the error.

Instead you should call the Method's 'invoke' method with an object of type URLClassLoader.

Comment: Thanks..I Tried that as well earlier but it gave ClassCastException:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader 
Code:
                  URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
                    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(classLoader, url);

Comment: Please refer to Holger's comment above. For this you should indeed create your own URLClassLoader instance and not use the ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() method.